# TCL Function throws an error

Tags: tcl

I have this function,

```
proc get_sys_status aname {
upvar $aname a

set input [exec "get system status\n" "# "]
set linelist [split $input \n]
foreach line $linelist 
{
    if {![regexp {([^:]+):(.*)} $line dummy key value]} 
        continue
    switch -regexp -- $key 
    {
        Hostname 
        {
            set a(hostname) [string trim $value]
        } 
    }
}
}

get_sys_status status
 
# line 17
puts "This machine is called $status(hostname)"
```

The general idea is that it takes the output of command “get system status” and parses the data. Once it parses this, it grabs the hostname and uses that to issue a few commands to the box. Error occurs at line 17 (the very last line):

```
can't read "status(hostname)": no such variable

----An error occured at line #17 of the script----

------- The end of log ----------
```

What is wrong with this function?

Comment: Is "get system status" really a command? In what OS?

Comment: Are you sure `key` ever gets the value "Hostname"? If I run your code substituting `set input "this:is\nHostname:a test"` for your `set input` line it works fine. If I change the line to `set input "this:is\nhostname:a test"` I get the error you report.

Comment: You wouldn't have got that _exact_ error out of running that script in a conventional Tcl interpreter. The syntax errors (e.g., from calling `foreach` or `if` wrong) will happen first! Braces matter in Tcl, as do newlines. When debugging, it can help to print out the exact string from things like the `exec` so that you can check what you've got back is what you're expecting…

Comment: The open brace of a `foreach`, `if`, `switch` and switch branch **must** be on the **same line** as the command. In Tcl, newlines are command separators. Your `foreach` statement does not have enough arguments.